# No module named tensorflow.python Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow, windows-10, artificial-intelligence, image-recognition

I'm trying to use [Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) for image recognition but I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "classify_image.py", line 46, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python'
```

Comment: Can you do a **pip3 list** from a Windows command prompt and check that tensorflow shows up in the list of installed packages? If not  It would be helpful to edit your question with steps you took to install tensorflow and any error messages seen to help with answering your question

Comment: Alright, I did that:
`C:\Users\Diederik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts>pip3 list
Package     Version
----------- -------
absl-py 0.3.0
astor 0.7.1
gast 0.2.0
grpcio 1.13.0
Markdown 2.6.11
numpy 1.15.0
pip 10.0.1
protobuf 3.6.0
setuptools  39.0.1
six 1.11.0
tensorboard 1.9.0
**tensorflow  1.9.0**
termcolor 1.1.0
Werkzeug 0.14.1
wheel 0.31.1
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.0 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
`